# Can a consumer wireless router act as both a wireless client and access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, tomato

I'm going to be moving in the future, and integrating my home network into that of my landlord. I wish to maintain an isolated network while using his internet connection, so I'm planning on cascading my router off of his (WAN-to-LAN type configuration). Unfortunately, it looks like it might not be feasible to run a wire between the two. Therefore, I'd like to send my WAN connection over WiFi to his router.

At my disposal, I have a WRT54GL (running Shibby's Tomato mod), and I just bought an Asus RT-N66U (I can be flexible with the firmware). My first thought was to set up the WRT as a wireless bridge, then run a wire between that and the N66U's WAN port. I'm reasonably sure I could make that work, but can I eliminate the WRT from the equation altogether? Can the N66U connect to the landlord's WiFi as a client, effectively using that as the WAN port, while simultaneously providing wireless access to my devices on an altogether different WLAN?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be made to work as long as you have two antennas which you can control seperately (I'm not sure if that's the case for the N66U, but my AC66U allows different settings for the 2.4 and 5 GHz interfaces).

Another option could be to use a USB wireless adapter to run on the router's USB.

You might have to manually tinker with the routing table so the default route goes out on the interface in client mode.

Comment: Interesting point about a USB wireless adapter... didn't know that was a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I know with DD-WRT firmwares, each interface (2.4GHz and 5GHz, along with each eth) are independently controlled.  If your landlord is broadcasting 5GHz, you could take your 5GHz radio and connect it to that network, and set the mode to "WAN Client - DHCP."  Then, with your 2.4GHz radio, simply set it up like you normally would with a "LAN - Infrastructure" model.

Answer (score 0):

You can check valid interface combinations with this command

```
iw list
```

Look for something like this

```
...
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2

...
```